# ¿Existe alguna palabra para expresar algo que es más que un deseo pero menos que una necesidad?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, sinónimos

Para dar un ejemplo, supongamos que a una persona le gusta mucho comer fruta , comer fruta para esta persona es un deseo, pero si bien no comer fruta podría (potencial) afectar su salud, no se va a morir por no comer fruta.

> La respuesta genérica es que si [sic] podemos vivir sin consumir frutas, pero la calidad de nuestra salud se puede ver seriamente afectada.

[Vivir sin comer frutas](https://www.alimentossas.com/vivir-sin-comer-frutas)

Pongo este ejemplo para evitar otros que son los que realmente quisiera dar, pero que son polémicos y que probablemente desvirtuarían la respuesta hacia otros temas. (Por ejemplo algunos profesionales de la salud recomiendan comer ciertas cosas o realizar ciertas actividades que si las planteas como "necesidad" de cara a la sociedad se arma la hecatombe).  ¿Existe alguna palabra para expresar algo que es más que un deseo pero menos que una necesidad?

Comment: Recomendable, recomendado, se recomienda.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Algo que deseas mucho mucho, pero que realmente no necesitas es un antojo o un capricho.

> [antojo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=2xdAves)
>
> 1. m. Deseo apremiante y pasajero, habitualmente caprichoso

Tienes también ["anhelo"](https://dle.rae.es/?id=2gDo6zM) como sinónimo de "Deseo vehemente" (esa es literalmente la definición del DRAE). Anhelo es también una de las acepciones de ["ansia"](https://dle.rae.es/?id=2ku73g2).

Si bien tener capricho o antojo tiene ciertas connotaciones de "deseo pasajero o momentáneo", con "anhelo" puedes expresar que el deseo es no tan transitorio.

Tienes también ["querencia"](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Uno4hNi)

> 4. f. Tendencia natural o de un ser animado hacia algo.

si quieres explicar que una persona tiene una potente inclinación o gusto por algo. Esto si bien no es una necesidad, tampoco implica que sea un deseo fuerte.

El término ["pasión"](https://dle.rae.es/?id=S4Caraz)

> 7. f. Apetito de algo o afición vehemente a ello.

sí que denota un grado "muy vivo de inclinación o preferencia" hacia algo.

> Tengo **pasión** por la fruta.

Comment: hmmm me refiero a algo que sea mas fuerte que un antojo. Querencia o pasion me dejan algunas dudas si podrian ser o no, seria una palabra que signifique algo que te afecte si no lo haces, pero no al punto de que no puedas vivir

Comment: De qué forma te afecta? Cuando la gente está dejando de fumar ti tiene "mono" (síndrome de abstinencia) les afecta a varios niveles, por no poder satisfacer eso que es un deseo fuerte (fumar) pero que no es una necesidad (de hecho es perjudicial). Esas personas tienen un **anhelo** (deseo vehemente) o **ansia** de algo.

Comment: Yo creo que anhelo es la palabra que mejor englobe la idea. Las otras tienen otras connotaciones que no encajan tanto

Comment: @guifa - Precisamente *anhelo* iba a proponer.  Va bien con la descripción de OP, si no del ejemplo.

Comment: Concuerdo con que esa palabra es **anhelo** (un deseo fuerte)

Comment: Creo que la palabra que mejor se ajusta es ansia

Answer (score 4):

Respuesta rápida:

**Necesario**

Implica que si no incluimos el consumo de frutas, nuestra salud se verá afectada pero la salud no se pone en peligro de forma directa.

---

Un término genérico es **bueno**. Por ejemplo,

> Es **bueno** incluir frutas en la dieta.

Significa que es deseable comerlas e implica beneficios (mas no el grado de estos). No implica ningún efecto negativo al no incluirlos.

Un nivel anterior al que buscas sería **importante**. Por Ejemplo,

> Es **importante** incluir frutas en la dieta.

Significa que incluir el consumo puede ser benéfico pero no necesariamente tendrá efectos negativos el no incluirlos.

En realidad, el término que buscas es precisamente **necesidad**. Por ejemplo,

> Es **necesario** incluir frutas en la dieta.

Significa que no incluir las frutas en la dieta podría tener efectos negativos en la salud pero no necesariamente pone en riesgo la vida.

Por otro lado, si quiero hacer énfasis en que el no comer frutas pondría en riesgo la vida yo usaría el término **indispensable**.

> Es **indispensable** incluir frutas en la dieta.

Si quiero poner aún mas énfasis yo usaría el término **vital**. Para dar un sentido de que su no inclusión *seguramente* pondría en peligro la vida, yo escribiría:

> Es **vital** incluir frutas en la dieta.

Si resumimos, en orden de importancia los términos serían:

> **bueno** (genérico, puede incluir los demás niveles)
>   **importante**
>   **necesario** (el que más se acerca al significado que buscas)
>   **indispensable**
>   **vital**

Quiero hacer notar que **bueno** tiene un rango muy amplio; es decir que puede ser sinónimo de los demás términos dependiendo del contexto en que se exprese; por ejemplo:

> Es **bueno** apagar la luz antes de salir de la casa.
>   Es **bueno** siempre poner atención mientras se conduce.

Como reflexión adicional, tenemos que tomar en cuenta que el español es muy flexible en el sentido de que nos permite usar las palabras como recursos retóricos.

> Para mi es **vital** salir de casa con el celular (móvil)

Por tal motivo, si bien la lista de términos puede ser una referencia, no es necesario seguirla al pie de la letra. En la expresión oral, se pueden usar sin problema uno o dos términos para referirse a cualquier grado de importancia debido a que el contexto está implícito y en su defecto el interlocutor puede pedir que se clarifique.

Comment: Pero no podemos usar "necesario" para explicar que algo es "menos que una necesidad". De igual manera "vital" o "indispensable" dicen que algo es **esencial** no un "deseo que en realidad no es necesario". Creo que en esos casos es más el contexto que el término en sí lo que nos da las connotaciones de "no me voy a morir si no tengo esto, pero para mi es muy importante hacerlo por X razones".